# Compile pthread.h stuff on AIX using g++

Tags: c++, gcc, posix, aix

I try to compile this very simplified program:

```
#include <pthread.h>

int main(){
    pthread_yield();
    return 0;
}
```

using -pthread like the IBM side says:

```
$ g++ -pthread test.cpp -o test
```

and get this error:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:4:15: error: 'pthread_yield' was not declared in this scope
pthread_yield();
```

I tried lots of other falgs too, but nothing worked so far. The pthread.h is in /usr/includes but pthread_yield() needs _AIX_PTHREADS_D7 defined.
Do I have to define this myselfe or is this done by adding some flag?

THX!

Comment: The `-pthread` flag should be all you need. Have you checked your installation? Can you re-install the compiler? What version of GCC are you using?

Comment: Does it work if you use standard C++ threads instead of pthreads?

Comment: Yes, you are to define this `_AIX_PTHREADS_D7` symbol manually. Yes, it's a bit lame, but `pthread_yield` _is_ a non-standard extension.

Comment: When I compile with -D_AIX_PTHREADS_D7 I get an undefined symbol error for pthread_yield, which brings me at least a step further, but explicitly linking to libpthread.a in /usr/lib doesn't solve the undefined symbol error.

Comment: @Galik GCC is 6.4.0 on AIX 7.1. Compiler re-installation is not possible.

Comment: @Shawn I tried to use std::this_thread::yield() and it faild like the posix stuff. Weird! I have some legacy code from apaches APR project that works, but so far I couldn't figure out how APR is doing the linking. Some black magic stuff in a 20k lines config script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than defining symbol `_AIX_PTHREADS_D7` you have to use library `libpthreads_compat` as well.

```
g++ -o marscode marscode.cc -D_AIX_PTHREADS_D7 -lpthreads_compat -lpthreads
```